# In Haskell, are guards or matchers preferable?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm learning Haskell, and it's not always clear to me when to use a matcher and when to use a guard.  For certain scenarios it seems that matchers and guards can be used to achieve essentially the same ends.  Are there some rules or heuristics for when it's better to use matches over guards or vice versa?  Is one more performant than the other?

To illustrate what I'm getting at, here are a couple of silly examples I cooked up that seem to be equivalent, but one version uses matchers and the other uses guards:

```
listcheck :: [a] -> String
listcheck [] = "List is null :-("
listcheck a = "List is NOT null!!"

listcheck' a
    | null a = "List is null :-("
    | otherwise = "List is NOT null!!"
```

and

```
luckyseven :: Int -> String
luckyseven 7 = "SO LUCKY!"
luckyseven b = "Not so lucky :-/"

luckyseven' c
    | c == 7 = "SO LUCKY!"
luckyseven' c = "Not so lucky :-/"
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would go with use pattern matches when you can, and guards when you must.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These can often be used interchangeably, but there are significant differences between the two.  Pattern matching can only occur on constructors, so computations can not be performed inside of a pattern, while guards are simply multi-branch if-else statements.  For example, I can't write a pattern equivalent of the following:

```
func :: Int -> Int
func x
    | even x = 3 * x
    | odd x  = 7 * x        -- alternatively "otherwise = 7 * x" to get rid of all those pesky compiler warnings
```

This just wouldn't be possible with just pattern matching.  You also can't do things like

```
func :: Int -> Maybe String
func x
    | x < 0     = Nothing
    | x == 0    = Just "Zero"
    | x < 20    = Just "Small"
    | x < 100   = Just "Big"
    | x < 1000  = Just "Huge"
    | otherwise = Just "How did you count that high?"
```

Conversely, guards using ADTs don't give you much information without helper functions.  If I had the type

```
data Expr
    = Literal Int
    | Add  Expr Expr
    | Mult Expr Expr
    | Negate Expr
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Using guards to write the equivalent of

```
eval :: Expr -> Int
eval (Literal i)  = i
eval (Add  e1 e2) = eval e1 + eval e2
eval (Mult e1 e2) = eval e1 * eval e2
eval (Negate e)   = negate (eval e)
```

would be a lot more verbose, difficult, and annoying.  In fact, at some level you'd have to resort to pattern matching to do things like

```
getLiteral :: Expr -> Int
getLiteral (Literal i) = i
getLiteral _           = error "Not a literal"
```

Which introduces functions that can `error`, which is bad.  In this case, using pattern matching is much preferred over using guards.

Comment: First example might give a non-exhaustive pattern warning, as it is unlikely that your Haskell compiler can tell that `forall x. even x || odd x ~= True`

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr. This is true, but I was going for clarity, not necessarily to avoid any possible warning the compiler could give me.  I had debated with myself whether to leave it as `otherwise = ...`, or put a comment on it, but just decided to leave it the way it is.

Comment: Just pointing it out as (sort of) another difference.  I agree that it doesn't detract from the answer significantly, which is why I upvoted.

Comment: Note that languages with more powerful capabilities can sometimes accomplish more with pattern matching. For instance, in Coq, you could write a proof of `forall x, even x \/ odd x` (with suitable inductive definitions of `even` and `odd`) and then pattern match on the structure of the proof applied to your variable.

Comment: In the first example, you will have to perform both the `even x` and `odd x` if the number turns out to be odd, which is obviously redundant. In this case the performance loss will be negligible but in general that wouldn't be the case. So here using `| otherwise = ...` is not only a style choice, but would give objectively superior performance.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular examples, I'd go with pattern matching, but would use _ where possible:

```
listCheck :: [a] -> String
listCheck [] = "List is null :-("
listCheck _  = "List is NOT null!!"
```

and

```
luckySeven :: Int -> String
luckySeven 7 = "SO LUCKY!"
luckySeven _ = "Not so lucky :-/"
```

That emphasizes that if the list isn't empty, or the Int isn't 7, nothing else matters, and you aren't going to use its particular value to produce the function result. bheklilr has capably pointed out places where one choice or the other is definitely preferable.